# JQuery Intellisense when jQuery is an embedded resource

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm trying to get Intellisense for jQuery when my jQuery file is an embedded resource. It doesn't work.

Here's what I have at the top of my script:

```
/// <reference name="MyUtilities.ClientDependencies.jquery-1.4.2.js" assembly="MyUtilities" />
```

Referencing the vsdoc file directly also doesn't work.

Any clues?